# AngularJS Directive, Insert HTML after element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantic-ui

In the app I'm working on, people's names are mentioned throughout the app. I want to be able to show a contact card on click for any person that shows up - basically a little popout with their contact information.

I'm using Angular for this, and have cobbled this together using a directive. The HTML looks like this:

```
<a class="user" ng-person person="{{event.actor}}">{{event.actor}}</a>
```

And, I've got a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('person', function($timeout){
  var link = function(scope, el, attr){
    var person = attr.person;
    $timeout(function(){
      $(el).popup();
    }, 0);
    el.after("<div class='ui special popup'><div class='ui header'>"+person+"</div></div>");
  }

  return {
    link: link
  }

});
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is using the directive to be able to tag elements where I want this to show up with 'ng-person', and have it insert the popup element directly after.

My main question is this: I'd like to break that string of HTML in the `el.after()` out into its own file, so it's easier to manage. Is there a good way to import an HTML string from another file into a directive like this?

Also - there may be a totally better way to do this altogether. If there is, I'm all ears.

FYI - I'm using [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/definition) for the UI portion of things, so the popup syntax is via their framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd like to load a separate HTML file other than re-usability?

Comment: The HTML is going to be a fair bit more complex, so it's easier to manage and maintain as a separate file instead of a string in the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent built-in way to do what you're trying to do! Use the [`$templateRequest` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) to pull down your HTML file from its server location. This is really handy because Angular will then cache this HTML, pulling it from cache instead of the server whenever you request it in the future!

However, if you're wanting to really do things the Angular way, it may make more sense to do something like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  // I recommend against something like 'ngPerson' since
  // ng prefix is usually used for Angular built-in directives
  .directive('abcPersonCard', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        person: '='
      },
      templateUrl: '/partials/abcPersonCard.html',
      // link, controller, etc.
    };
  }
```

Then in your template...

/partials/abcPersonCard.html

```
<a class="user">{{person}}</a>
<div class="card">
  <!-- card stuff -->
</div>
```

And then you would use it like this instead of the regular link anywhere you want a card:

```
<abc-person-card person="event.actor"></abc-person-card>
```

Comment: Thanks Seth! Didn't know about that service, good to know. I'd need to pass data to the template (the person's name, etc.) - it doesn't appear that I'd be able to set a data context for the template using $templateRequest, or am I missing something?

Comment: What you could do, if you wanted to go that route (though it seems you've already figured out a better way), is this: you could use the [`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) on the HTML from your `$templateRequest` call and inject that into your DOM. Then, viola! You've got the resulting HTML from Angular's interpretation of your template.

Comment: Nice, I like it! Thanks a bunch. Wish I could accept two answers ;) This is great to remember for the future tho.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion to you would be to wrap this up into a directive who includes also the person (with ng-if ) and the main element
you could then use the controller to change whatever works to show that info
you'll be in charge of all that is happening

Comment: Thought of this approach right after I posted the question, and I'm thinking this makes the most sense. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend one directive with a template which has both the anchor and the div content:

```
app.directive('actor', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { person: '=' },
      templateUrl: 'person.html'
   }
});
```

Person.html

```
<a class="user">{{person.actor.name}}</a>
<div class="ui special popup">
    <div class="ui header"> 
       {{ person.actor.age }}
     </div>
 </div>");
```

Usage

```
<actor person="famousPerson"></actor>
```

This arrangement allows you to have full control over the HTML with access to `person` and any bindings you want to create.